# How to put different prices for configurable child products in CSV import export?

Tags: magento-1.9

Importing the CSV with some configurable product, how I can input the different price for every simple product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use column with heading lable '_super_attribute_price_corr' to input you price for every child product. If you want to add the price simple enter the amout, if you want add the percentage than simply add percentage with percent symbol, Like (10%).